# Seeking STL-aware c++filt

Tags: c++, stl, name-mangling, c++filt, demangler

In my development environment, I'm compiling a code base using GNU C++ 3.4.6. Code is under development, and unfortunately crashes now and then. It's nice to be able to run the traceback through a demangler, and I use c++filt 3.4. The problem comes when functions have a number of STL parameters. Consider

```
My_callback::operator()(
   Status&,
   std::set<std::string> const&,
   std::vector<My_parameter*> const&,
   My_attribute_set const&,
   std::vector<My_parameter_base*> const&,
   std::vector<My_parameter> const&,
   std::set<std::string> const&
)
{
   // ...
}
```

When this function is in the traceback, the mangled output on my platform is:

```
(_ZN30My_callbackclER11StatusRKSt3setISsSt4lessISsESaISsEERKSt6vectorIP13My_parameterSaISB_EERK17My_attribute_setRKS9_IP18My_parameter_baseSaISK_EERKS9_ISA_SaISA_EES8_+0x76a) [0x13ffdaa]
```

c++filt kindly demangles it to

```
(My_callback::operator()(Status&, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&, std::vector<My_parameter*, std::allocator<My_parameter*> > const&, My_attribute_set const&, std::vector<My_parameter_base*, std::allocator<My_parameter_base*> > const&, std::vector<My_parameter, std::allocator<My_parameter> > const&, std::set<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)+0x76a) [0x13ffdaa]
```

This is the same problem as compiler errors encountered when using templates. However, the STL is a fairly regular and recognizable package of templates. So what I'm hoping is that someone out there has created an enhanced version of c++filt which would dump something closer to the original function signature. Any hints?

Comment: Not to do with your question, but that's a pretty horrible function! Seven parameters, all of complex types - I'd say a little refactoring is more than overdue.

Comment: Neil, I agree with you, but I am not the owner of the code. It just shows up in my tracebacks (names have been changed to protect the guilty) ;^(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) simplifies and/or reformats long-winded C++ error and warning messages, with a focus on STL-related diagnostics. The result renders many of even the most cryptic diagnostics comprehensible.